# Why some elements of gradient are NaN in MMRM model?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am using MMRM in R. My response variable is a score and my fixed effects are base, group, visit, and group*visit. My code is as follows;

> SOFA_mmrm <- mmrm(    formula = Sofa_score~ base + GROUP + visit  +
> GROUP*visit +
> us(visit | DSRANDI),
> data = sofa_add,
> reml = TRUE,    control = mmrm_control(method = "Kenward-Roger" , vcov ="Kenward-Roger-Linear"))

However, there is a error as follows:

> Error in (function (formula, data, weights, reml = TRUE, covariance =NULL,  :    some elements of gradient are NaN at starting parameter
> values In addition: Warning message: In mmrm(formula = Sofa_score ~base + GROUP + visit + GROUP * visit +  :   Divergence with optimizer L-BFGS-B due to problems: L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'